# Spring Batch reading file with related records

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

i am using spring batch to read a flat file. The file has related records. ie, there can be a parent record and any number of child records i wanted to read all the records and call web service to store it. I also wanted to capture the relationship and store it.one challenge is child record can be anywhere in the file. And child can also have many children records.I am unable to find the solution for this problem with spring batch. 
please provide your suggestions

update: I dont have any option to use database as temporary storage of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved such problem by processing the file multiple times.

On every pass I'll try to read\process every record in the file with such alg:

- if record has parent - check if parent already stored. If no - I skip it in processor
- if record unchanged (or already stored if updates are not possible) - skip it in processor
- else - store in db

And then declare loop and decider:

```
    <batch:step id="processParentAndChilds" next="loop">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="processParentAndChildsReader"
                         commit-interval="1000">
                <batch:processor>
                    <bean class="processParentAndChildsProcessor"/>
                </batch:processor>
                <batch:writer>
                    <bean class="processParentAndChildsWriter"/>
                </batch:writer>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:decision decider="processParentAndChildsRetryDecider" id="loop">
        <batch:next on="NEXT_LEVEL" to="processprocessParentAndChilds"/>
        <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="goToNextSteps"/>
    </batch:decision> 


public class ProcessParentAndChildsRetryDecider implements JobExecutionDecider{
@Override
public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // if no on record written - no sense to try again
    if (stepExecution.getWriteCount() > 0) {
        return new FlowExecutionStatus("NEXT_LEVEL");
    } else {
        return FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Michail. I have used another approach.  I have a step in which i iterate through the file and create an in memory map(readers reads file and processor creates map. Writer is a no-op writer). I save this context and in next step i read through the map and create the domain object and required relationships. I know if the file is huge it will create memory leaks.I can buy more memory for this processing & solve memory issues. as i need to avoid processing the file multiple times. thanks anyway